# Image upload in multipart format using AFnetworking not working in ios

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, cocoa, afnetworking

1. AFHTTPSessionManager is used to post file from ios app
2. The server side is implemented using php
3. Server accepts the file if it is send from a web server

My iOS Code is

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Fb-button"];

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

AFHTTPSessionManager *sessionManager  = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithBaseURL:@"baseurl"];

AFJSONResponseSerializer *jsonresponseSerilaizer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];

jsonresponseSerilaizer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json",@"text/plain",@"text/html", nil];

sessionManager.responseSerializer = jsonresponseSerilaizer ;

[sessionManager POST:@"pathurl" parameters:Nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

    [formData appendPartWithFileData: imageData name:@"userfile" fileName:@"userfile.png" mimeType:@"png"];

} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"success");

    NSLog(@"response : %@",responseObject);

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"error");

    NSLog(@"error : %@",error);

}];
```

The error i get in xcode is cocoa error 3840

`error : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0x79865f70 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0., NSUnderlyingError=0x798665c0 "Request failed: bad request (400)"}`

The PHP code is given below

```
$user_image              =   $_FILES['user_image']['name'];
$config['upload_path']   = './images/User_files/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['file_name']     = $user_image;
$config['max_size']      = '100';
$config['max_width']     = '1024';
$config['max_height']    = '768';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
{
    $data["error"] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

    echo json_encode($data);
}
else
{
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

    echo '{"success": "true"}';
}
```

And also i tried following php code:

```
if($_FILES['user_image']['size'] > 0) 
{
    $user_image = substr(number_format(time() * rand(), 0, '', ''), 0, 8);

    if (preg_match('/^image\/p?jpeg$/i', $_FILES['user_image']['type']) or 
        preg_match('/^image\/gif$/i', $_FILES['user_image']['type']) or 
        preg_match('/^image\/jpg$/i', $_FILES['user_image']['type']) or 
        preg_match('/^image\/(x-)?png$/i', $_FILES['user_image']['type'])) 
    { 
        if (preg_match('/^image\/p?jpeg$/i', $_FILES['user_image']['type'])) 
        { 
            $ext = '.jpg'; 
        } 
        else if (preg_match('/^image\/gif$/i', $_FILES['user_image']['type']))
        { 
            $ext = '.gif'; 
        }
        else if (preg_match('/^image\/jpg$/i', $_FILES['user_image']['type']))
        { 
            $ext = '.jpg'; 
        } 
        else if (preg_match('/^image\/(x-)?png$/i', $_FILES['user_image']['type'])) 
        { 
            $ext = '.png'; 
        }

        $user_image = $user_image.$ext;
        $user_imagetoStore = './images/User_files/'.$user_image;
        copy($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'],$user_imagetoStore);
    }
    else
    {
        $user_image= "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

1. The Objective-C code is using field named `userfile` and the PHP snippets are using `user_image`.
2. The second PHP code snippet does not generate any JSON response.
3. I'd also suggest simply:

   ```
   sessionManager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
   ```

   It probably doesn't matter, but I'd also use `nil` rather than `Nil` when you call `POST` method.
4. If the above doesn't work, I'd also suggest running this on the simulator and watching this in Charles (http://charlesproxy.com) and see if the request looks OK.